# Can I build a Frontend in FlutterFlow then export to Flutter to finish coding?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I am learning flutter and dart at the moment. I came across FlutterFlow and I was wondering, could I use FlutterFlow to build the UI of the app, then turn around, take the code, and add it to my IDE and finish coding it with Flutter and dart there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I found, you can view the code of the UI and copy it from **Developer Menu -> View Code** as shown in the following image:

[image: FlutterFlow (View Code)]

You will see the code with a copy button in the top right corner as shown in the following image:

[image: FlutterFlow (Code)]

**Bounce:**
When you click on a widget in the screen, it shows only the code of it to let you focus on its implementation.

**Edit:**
In the same developer menu, there is a **Download Code** button which allows you to download the source code of the application but it's not available in the Free Plan, Standard and Pro only.

**Lastly:** As a piece of personal advice, if you are learning Flutter, then stay away from tools like FlutterFlow until you reach a good level in Flutter Development, so these tools become just an acceleration for your work, not too highly dependent on them.

Comment: Do we know if the code itself works? As mentioned I'm still learning to code with Flutter so I'm unaware of the commands or how to check or modify the FlutterFlow code (if possible) . I was wanted to see if there was a way to do it before I wasted time learning both. I've searched for about an hour but no luck.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the code generated by FlutterFlow, but as a piece of personal advice, if you are learning Flutter, then stay away from FlutterFlow until you reach a good level in Flutter Development, so tools like FlutterFlow become just a tool to accelerate your work, not to depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You must either be using the "standard" plan to be able to export the source code of the app or, if you just need a tool to create the UI for a flutter app, you can then use the [playground area of flutterflow](https://playground.flutterflow.io/) to have access to the source code of that view.